# Unterschied zwischen “Ausschuss” und “Gremium”

Tags: difference, word-choice

I have checked Google translate and leo.de. However, I wasn't able to discern the difference between the two words, because both seem to translate generically to *committee*.  What is the difference between *Ausschuss* and *Gremium*?

Comment: Also read this Meta post: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-for-translations-or-about-differences

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ausschuss* is possibly best matched by *subcommittee*: a group elects a subgroup to deal with a special topic. Currently well known due to press coverage are the *Untersuchungsausschüsse* from the German Bundestag.

A *gremium* ist just a sort of established group: examples are standardization groups, where industry chooses the delegates, *Mitbestimmungsgremien* like pupil parent association, representation of the workforce in companies and many more.

Summarized: any *Ausschuss* is also a *Gremium*, but not vice versa.

Comment: This should probably be a separate question, but how does "Behoerde" fit in relation to the other two words?  Here I'm thinking of a book by Jurek Becker: "Irrefuehrung der Behoerde."

Comment: @Ted Yes that should definitely be a different question. (a.k.a. please don't ask questions in comments but start a new question instead ;))